# How to give unique SESSION id to each <html><table><tr></tr></table></html> in PHP

Tags: php, session

Ok, I want to know how to `generate unique $_SESSION name or ID` and `set it to each table row` in `members.php` file, so when I click to any row in this file it will redirected to another file named `details.php` that reads the details from MySQL according to that row( in my code the details of 'member') and prints out it.

### members.php:

```
<?php session_start();?>
<html>
<table>
<?php
  include 'connect.php';/*make connection to MySQL*/
  $stmt=$mysqlConnect->query('SELECT name, phone FROM members');
  foreach($stmt as $row)
  { 
    $name = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;/*HELP: this is where I am strugling*/
    /*the value of $_SESSION['name'] is changes each time in loop.*/ 
    /*So, it works only for last row of table named 'members' */
    /*in MySQL database.*/
?>
 <tr onclick="window.document.location='details.php';">
    <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']?></td> 
    <?php 
      }/*end of froeach function*/
      mysqlConnect=null;/*disconnect mysql*/
    ?>
 </tr>
```

### details.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include "connect.php";
  $name = $_SESSION['name']/*HELP: */
  $stmt = $mysqlConnect->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE name = Sname");

  foreach($stmt as $row)
  {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['adress'];
    echo $row['mail'];
    echo $row['phone'];
    echo $row['car'];
    echo $row['credit'];
    echo $row['workDay'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: Instead of `="details.php"` do `="details.php?name=" . $row['name']`, then you have `$_GET['name']` in details php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an array out of `$_SESSION['name']`, but it will not solve your problem. There is only one set of session information per session (per browser, not per tab), so when opening the details, you would still need to know which one was clicked by passing some information in the request (get/querystring or post information).

Using that information, you could set the right name again in the session, but that could cause a side effect: When you open member A in a new tab, the session name is set to A. Then you open member B in other new tab and the session name is set to B. Because the session is shared between all tabs in the browser, refreshing the details of member A would now suddenly result in the details of member B.

So it's better to just pass the name in the url, and show the details based on that. Alternatively, you could `post` the information, but for that you need more javascript and/or an html form, both of which will make things more complex than needed.

So, instead of setting the session information or *post*ing data, you can simply pass the name (or an id) into the url when you click it. Notice the addition of `urlencode` to make the url valid even if there are special characters in the name.

```
<html>
<table>
<?php
  include 'connect.php';/*make connection to MySQL*/
  $stmt=$mysqlConnect->query('SELECT name, phone FROM members');
  foreach($stmt as $row)
  { 
?>
 <tr onclick="window.document.location='details.php?name=<?php echo urlencode($row['name'])?>';">
    <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']?></td> 
<?php 
  }/*end of foreach function*/
  mysqlConnect = null;/*disconnect mysql*/
?>
 </tr>
```

In the other page, you can read the value from the `$_GET` superglobal. With some additional checks, your page may look like this. I've made some additions to make reading from the database safer. I assumed you are using MySQLi. If not (PDO or a custom class), you may need to make some changes.

```
<?php
  include "connect.php";

  // Check, if no name was given, someone visited the page directly. 
  // Redirect to the member list in that case.
  if (!isset($_GET['name'])) {
    header('Location: members.php');
    exit;
  }

  $name = $_GET['name'];

  // Use a prepared statement. This is safer, otherwise people could secretly
  // enter pieces of malicious SQL into the 'name' querystring.
  $stmt = $mysqlConnect->prepare(
    "SELECT
      name, address, mail, phone, car, credit, workDay
    FROM members WHERE name = ?");
  $stmt->bind_param('s', Sname);

  $result = $stmt->execute();

  // You can bind result parameters too. This will fetch each row directly 
  // into these variables.
  $stmt->bind_result($name, $address, $mail, $phone, $car, $credit, $workDay);

  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $name;
    echo $address;
    echo $mail;
    echo $phone;
    echo $car;
    echo $credit;
    echo $workDay;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and better solution is **avoid using session and use GET to pass value to details.php**

```
<html>
<table>
<?php
    foreach($stmt as $row)
    {
    $name = $row['name'];
    ?>
    <tr onclick="window.document.location='details.php?name=<?php echo $name;  ?>';">
    <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']?></td>
    <?php
    }/*end of froeach function*/
    mysqlConnect=null;/*disconnect mysql*/
    ?>
</tr>
```

then for details.php

```
$name = $_GET['name']  /* Use $_GET instead of session */
```